# ¿Cómo puedo agregar el botón de mi ubicación en un mapa de Android Studio?

Tags: android

Tengo el siguiente código que no añade ningún botón:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
            (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
            (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }else {};
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola Issac Flores en el caso de que quieras que se habilite elboton de ubicación en tu mapa  podrias utilizar `mMap.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true` en el caso de que sea en Kotlin, y el caso de JAVA `mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);`.

Esta opción activara en tu mapa el boton para poder ubicarte.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer]. Así tu respuesta, no será reportada como de baja calidad por su extensión y contenido. Normalmente es mucho más agradecido que expliques el porque de la solución.

Comment: Intente colocar lo que mencionó, pero en "uiSettings" dice que no se puede resolver, le agradecería que me indique como colocarlo o cual es mi error, si falta colocar alguna linea antes o algo porfavor.

Comment: el lenguaje que estas usando es JAVA? o KOTLIN?

Comment: No le hagan caso a esos bots de admin, Uno da respuesta bien y te salen como que esta mal. jajaja.

Comment: No me funciona ese código, ni en un dispositivo físico ni en el emulador de andorid, cree que sea por alguna razón externa? quizá por el api? gracias de antemano